# Eclipse RCP - dynamically alter PATH variable

Tags: eclipse, dll, native, rcp

My RCP application needs native .dll libraries.
Such libraries are over 150MBs in size and most users already have such libraries on their PC.
I don't want to re-distribute the native libs with my application. On the contrary, I'd like users to select a path to the existing installation on their file system. Such path would then be added to the PATH variable dynamically.
Does anyone know a way to do so?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying PATH at runtime from the application itself looks not feasible.
The only possibility would be to use an installer which allows users to select the location of the native libraries, altering the PATH accordingly at installation time.